# How to boot from sda disk sytem installed on nvme drive? Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, nvme

I just tuned up my laptop (Dell E5250) by installing nvme m.2 drive into PCIe (WWAN) port. Ubuntu recognize drive, but bios(uefi) doesn't see nvme. Otherwise there is installed sata (sda) disk with system.
I tried to install grub and boot folder on sda disk and system on nvme disk, but after start computer, there are some errors:

```
error: no such device:7110c-very-log-number..
error: file ~/boot/vmlinuz-5.11..... not found.
error: you need to install kernel first.

Press any key to continue...
```

Which files and folders shoud I install on sda drive to propper boot system?
I would like to use all system from nvme drive not only /home folder.
Could You help me please?

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware? And often NVMe, even new, may need new firmware also.UEFI should see NVMe drive in UEFI settings (F2) or else no system will see it. But if not seen as bootable device (F12)  then boot mode may be incorrect. Are all systems in UEFI boot mode?

Comment: That's the point of my question. My UEFI Bios don't recognize nvme drive, but linux and windows -yes. I can use its disk as storage (i.e documents folder or home folder) but I would like to use it for system. It could improve prefromance of my system.

Comment: Did you update UEFI firmware from Dell? And SSD firmware?

Comment: I forgot to describe that this laptop NOT support nvme disks. I can and I want to that by core drivers. But yes, firmware is up to date.

Answer (score 3):

You can put `/boot` into a separate boot partition in a drive that is recognized at boot. Then the system will see your nvme drive and you can have your root partition **`/`** (and `/home` partition if you have one) in the nvme drive.

I have installed a system like that in one of my computers, and it works well for me.

Comment: I did it like that. The result I described above. Is your nvme disk recognize in BIOS?

Comment: @DrupalSeb, No, in my computer, a Lenovo Thinkstation C30, the nvme card is not in the BIOS list of bootable drives.

Comment: one step more. It works as You described, but as legacy boot, not uefi.  I will check it one more time. Thank You!